# How are pocket dimensions created in multiplayer games programming-wise?

Tags: software-engineering, game-mechanics

How do multiplayer games deal with multiple instances/dungeons/regions? I'm familiar with server clustering which is what larger games use such as Eve and World of Warcraft.

How do games such as Minecraft deal with the pocket dimensions such as the nether and ender with multiplayer compatibility?

Lastly, are there any existing game engines that support the single dedicated server with multiple pocket dimensions setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer on Minecraft, specifically, as I've done some modding, so I'm aware of the generalities.

Minecraft has a class object called `World`.  This handles everything about the world of Minecraft: the blocks, the entities, the weather, etc.  Anything that happens happens inside the world object.  `World` contains a dynamic list of loaded chunks, chunks contain a (list of (list of(list of integers))) representing blocks (and yes, it really is that bad: blocks are actually stored as three! separate 3D arrays segmented into 16 blocks of height: one array holds the 8 LSB, another holds the 4 MSB, and another holds the 4 bit metadata).

Different dimensions have their *own instances* of a World object, which is why its often referred to by modders as a "poor name" for the class, it should be `Dimension` as more traditionally the World object is a singleton responsible for handling the primary state machine of the game.

For Minecraft, that singleton happens to be the `Minecraft` class (client side) or `MinecraftServer` (server side) [footnote: I have a feeling I am mis-remembering the main class for the server].  The current "integrated server, making SSP functionally SMP with 1 player" is just a little hocus pocus in having separated all of the singleton logic out of the client classes and then packaging the server classes *with* the client and calling it the "integrated server" while silently hiding the fact that the game connects to itself on 127.0.0.1 (note: I've not looked into the actual workings of this, so there's some guesswork here). All packet handling (typical for a remote connection) works as expected in this way.

Note that there is also a `WorldClient` class, which stores the state of the world for the client to reference when rendering and performing interpolation on movement, it acts just like the standard copy the server has, but changes to this `World` are not sent to the server and the server sending data back will override. New modders often make this mistake and end up with holes in the world that act like the blocks are still there (can't walk through it, make the player and other entities rubber band, etc).

So as far as the game is concerned, separate dimensions can't affect one another except through very limited ways (teleporting) so it can keep the unviewed chunks unloaded when no one is there.  If someone does go there, the chunks are loaded into memory and processed just like any other chunk, but part of a separate `World` (the server maintains a list--likely a Map--of dimensions that can be accessed by integer ID).  The teleportation itself is a bit of a hack, as it literally clones whatever entity went to the new dimension, spawning the new copy at the destination, and garbage collecting the old one.